# how would I handle a Exception in this program?

Tags: java, exception

this is the program I am working with, it takes 4 int's and finds the area of them. I need to put an Exception that detects if the user doesn't type a int and a string instead. I want it tell the user ("Numbers only")

```
package areacircle;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AreaCircleTwoPointO {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print ("Type The x1 point please: ");
    int x1 = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.print ("Type The x2 point please: ");
    int x2 = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.print ("Type The y1 point please: ");
    int y1 = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.print ("Type the y2 point please: ");
    int y2 = reader.nextInt();
    double area = areaCircle(x1, x2, y1, y2);
    System.out.println ("The area of your circle is: " + area);
}
    public static double distance
           (double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    double dx = x2 - x1;
    double dy = y2 - y1;
    double dsquared = dx*dx + dy*dy;
    double result = Math.sqrt (dsquared);
    return result;
}

public static double areaCircle(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    double secretSauce = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    return areaCircleOG(secretSauce);
}

public static double areaCircleOG(double secretSauce)
{
    double area = Math.PI * Math.pow(secretSauce, 2);
    return area;
}
}
```

I have somewhat of an idea will look like here it is..

```
    public static int getPoints()
    {
    int age = -1;
    boolean continueLoop = true;

    while (continueLoop)
    {
        String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter point x1: ");
        try {
           age = Integer.parseInt (inputStr);
           continueLoop = false;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Age must be an integer!!");
        }
    }
    return age;
}
```

but the thing about this is that it is using JOptionPane and I don't want to use JOptionPane, just scanner.

Comment: You want to use Scanner to show a message? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please clarify your question. How do you want the error message to be shown?

Comment: You will print out to console if you dont want to use a message box. The lines that read int = reader.nextInt(); will throw an exception if the input isnt a number. Put that call in some method which returns the value, and make that call in a try/catch wrapped in an while. Attempt to get the input from the user while you havent got a valid one yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);

    boolean finished = false;
    while(!finished)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.print ("Type The x1 point please: ");
            int x1 = reader.nextInt();
            System.out.print ("Type The x2 point please: ");
            int x2 = reader.nextInt();
            System.out.print ("Type The y1 point please: ");
            int y1 = reader.nextInt();
            System.out.print ("Type the y2 point please: ");
            int y2 = reader.nextInt();
            double area = areaCircle(x1, x2, y1, y2);
            System.out.println ("The area of your circle is: " + area);
            double area = areaCircle(x1, x2, y1, y2);
            System.out.println ("The area of your circle is: " + area);
            finished = true;
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Please type in a number! Try again.");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: thank you very much 

minecrafter338 this answered my question exactly